# wordpress not including javascript on generated page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am having issues with javascript functionality not working in the admin area.
When writing a new post things like the ScreenOptions button or the Publish box do not work.

I have a local wordpress development install and a deployment install on the live site.
Locally is working. I have compared the generated HTML for the post-new.php of both sites and they are different.

The one that does not work is failing to include some javascript into the file.
So, in the working file I have some javascript inside script tags that is missing in the file not working.

Why would that be?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failed to mention the plugins I was using.

Wordpress 2.8.2., Magic Fields Version 1.3.1 to generate custom write panels.
Then I have WPML 1.7.1 and Akismet 2.2.7 in the live. No other plugins.

I was going to comment that but it made me think that perhaps the error was with Magic Fields.

Sure enough, found something. If you go to file RCCWP_Processor, line 368:

```
add_action('admin_print_scripts', array( 'RCCWP_WritePostPage',
'CustomFieldsJavascript' ));
```

If you change `admin_print_scripts` to `admin_head` it starts working for me.

```
add_action('admin_head', array( 'RCCWP_WritePostPage',
'CustomFieldsJavascript' ));
```